# How to Tether NordVPN internet from Android to Laptop?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, linux, vpn, oneplus-two, oxygenos

I tether my internet with my phone. 
I connect with my laptop to it. 
If I keep my VPN client (NordVPN) activet, internet does not work.

NordVPN support says to configure VPN in Settings > VPN. 
However, I want to use many VPN servers so manually setting each there is not possible. 
NordVPN frontend has a nice map where you can choose which VPN server to use. 
Internet works with VPN in my phone but not in my laptop when it is using the tethered source.

**Differential condition**: NordVPN Android application does not keep VPN active all the time

- complication: Client laptop cannot get internet in USB tethering when VPN is active in the phone

I forwarded this thread (26.9.2016, 3.10.2016 and 4.10.2016) to the NordVPN support and stated a deep wish to get a manual about using NordVPN internet from phone with your Debian laptop. 
Feel free to ask me more details about the test configuration if needed. 
Questions of the tech support

1. *Does [Android NordVPN] disconnect when you are browsing or not launching at all?* It disconnects itself when browsing internet.
2. *Can you give more information about our application not keeping connection at all time. How often you are getting disconnect and on what event it disconnects ( i.e. when you lock your phone or when it fall in sleep for not using it).* It occurs daily. It occurs when I lock my phone.

Phone: Oneplus 2
Phone OS: 3.1 OxygenOS
Laptop: Asus Zenbook UX303UA
Laptop OS: Debian 8.5 64 bit
Laptop Linux kernel: 4.6 of backports
VPN client in Android: NordVPN (tried many locations)

Comment: I use an android device (Samsung J7) with nordvpn active and my laptop tethers fine (wireless). Additionally I use vpn on laptop at same time and it still seems to works fine. As far as I can tell my ip is hidden and on public wifi networks I am not able to be seen.

Comment: With root access it's possible to manually add network routes to force redirect all traffic through VPN interface: [How to share VPN connection with devices on hotspot?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216050/218526)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How to Tether NordVPN internet from Android to Laptop?

Answer from NordVPN support of ID #555274

> Unfortunately, when you are using VPN your device automatically becomes unreachable to any other devices due to safety so sadly you won't be able to use usb tether while VPN is active.

I asked further why this is going to be changed in NordVPN. 
Why it cannot be guaranteed at the moment?

> Unfortunately, it's technically impossible to make a device to be
>   reachable when it uses VPN. Maybe someday someone will find how to
>   make unreachable device to become reachable when VPN is active but for
>   know there is no solution.

I think this is not right because you can create a virtual machine which handles the ports for you. 
Please, see

- My Apple threads but applicable in Linux [How to Mimic Location of Slave VPN for Primary VPN?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/239363/15504) since you cannot split the tunneling as observed in the thread [How to Do Split Tunnelling with Slave ppp0 VPN + 2nd VPN?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/286220/16920)

**Differential solution**: 
Same security policy is used with `openvpn` terminal application in Debian OS. 
So it can be easier to test it first there and understand the situation better.

### Differential condition: NordVPN Android application does not keep VPN active all the time

> When you lock your phone the internet might disconnect for few seconds
>   because of battery save feature on phone. However it should reconnect
>   when you unlock your phone.

I think the battery save explanation is sound here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are rooted you can use tethernet,  hot-spot on the vpn then tethernet then connect to pc/laptop, you can't do Android to Android tho.   it's worked on HTC m8,  m9, 10, u11,  u11+ & u12+ . I would look on xda  if you are not rooted.  https://forum.xda-developers.com/oneplus-2/general/guides-how-to-guides-beginners-t3146568
Hope this helps