# How can I share my free internet vpn connection with my laptop?

Tags: internet, wifi-hotspot

I am getting the free internet connection through both HTTP Injector and Anonytun, I want to get the same fast connection in my laptop as in the android phone?
Please use simple language since I'm not exactly very convulsant with these things..but I,m also not thaat dumb...hehe :-). Thank you.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to share VPN connection with devices on hotspot?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/216033/218526)

Answer (score 2):

The easy Way...
 1. Start your VPN on your phone
 2. Install/Use Clockworkmod's USB Tether.
2b. Use PDANet/Foxfi for wireless sharing.

The Clockworkmod/PDAnet tether app will connect to the internet like any other app; 
through the VPN.

Comment: Paid apps, depend on Wi-Fi Direct.