# How can I set up DNS OVER HTTPS in Android 8?

Tags: dns

I am using android hotspot as wifi for my devices, and I want to set up DOH on my android, how can I do it?

PS: I have tried to install Intra or other APPs that can only change dns for internet access directly from Android, not from other devices that using the Android hotspot.

Comment: According to [this post](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-change-dns-on-android-4588645) the central DNS setting (including the private DNS feature) on Android was introduced with Android 9.

Comment: Run `dnscrypt-proxy`. Root method is here: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/207647/218526. But it's also possible to run it with Android's built-in VPN feature, without having root.

Comment: @lrfan  do you know if `dnscrypt-proxy` is also working for sharing hotspot wifi from carriers cellular data?  It seems the hostpot pretend a wifi and I not sure if this wifi dns still use the android system dns.

Comment: @Robert Have you tried in Android 9? try to enable hotspot and let other device connect this hotspot, then test your dns in the device to see if the dns is what you set in the Android 9.

Comment: @novice it depends on which method you use to redirect DNS traffic towards `dnscrypt-proxy`. In case of root it's the robust `iptables`. So not even a single packet can escape from it. In case of VPN based redirection, it's not very likely because network traffic doesn't go through VPN connections. See explanation [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216050/218526) (though the question is different).